# Preencher automaticamente células no excel usando VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, loop, excel-vba, do-while

Boa tarde comunidade,

Ando a tentar trabalhar com o VBA no Excel de modo a tentar aplicar esse conhecimento na minha tese de mestrado, mas estou com algumas dúvidas.

Eu estou a tentar criar uma função em VBA que preencha células consoante um determinado valor. Na imagem seguinte tenho dois quadros, um com valores nos vértices e outro todo preenchido pelo valor 1. O quadro da esquerda, representa uma câmara de vigilância, que está na célula B1.
No quadro da direita é suposto aparecer a área de cobertura dessa mesma câmara. A área da câmara ocupa 10 células.

O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
Sub Limpar()
Range("G5:J8") = ""
End Sub

Sub Executar()
If Cells(5, "B").Value = 1 Then Preencher
End Sub

Sub Preencher()
Dim contador As Integer
contador = 10
Do While contador > 0
Range("G5:J8") = 1
contador = contador - 1
Loop
End Sub
```

E o seu resultado é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver a minha função preenche tudo, e o objectivo era só preencher 10 células.
O que pretendia era algo parecido ao que está na imagem seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como fazer em VBA para no quadro da direita apresentar só o número de células preenchidas pela área da câmara? Que neste caso deveriam aparecer 10 células preenchidas.
Eu sei que o meu código preenche o quadro todo, mas não era isso que eu estava a tentar, eu queria era preencher quadrícula a quadrícula até que perfizesse as 10 quadrículas correspondentes à área da câmara da célula B5.

Se eu conseguir para uma câmara, provavelmente conseguirei para outras câmaras de áreas diferentes e colocadas em vértices diferentes.

Obrigado para quem me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta definindo um limite de alcance e a partir disso subtrair os valores, algo nesse gênero:

```
Sub preencherCameras()
Dim Limite, Linha, Coluna As Integer
Limite = 4

    Linha = Application.ActiveCell.Row 'Linha Atual

    For y = 0 To Limite - 1 'Repetir até o Limite Alcance
        Coluna = Application.ActiveCell.Column 'Coluna Atual
        For x = 1 To Limite
            Cells(Linha + y, Coluna) = 1
            Coluna = Coluna + 1
        Next x
    Limite = Limite - 1 'Diminuir o limite
    Next y

End Sub
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se for algo simples e fixo, basta criar 4 "Ifs" destes:

```
If Range("b5") = 1 Then
Range("g5,H5, I5,J5, G6, H6, I6, g7, h7, g8") = 1
End If
```